# image resize by adding values to retried width and height of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have an series of images whose width and height varies. in my application i need to gradually grow image when it gets focus.after image loads i have used

var w='img.width' 
var h='img.height'

to get width and height of image. now how do i add some value say 10px to both width and height so that i can pass this values to grow function.

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 

   $(window).load(function(){
  var timer = null;

$(function() {
    $('button:has(img)').focus(function() {
        var $image = $(this).find('img');
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
        var w = 'img.width';
        var h = 'img.height';
        var zoominw= w+10;
        var zoominh=h+10;
            $image.animate({
                'width': 'zoominw',
                'height': 'zoominh'
            }, 500);
        }, 2000);
    }).blur(function() {
        if (timer != null)
            clearTimeout(timer);
        $(this).find('img').animate({
            'width': 'imgwidth',
            'height': 'imgheight'
        }, 500);
    });
});
  });

  </script>
```

Comment: http://www.eyecon.ro/zoomimage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) of an element use something like this:

```
var image = $(this).find('img');
var w = image.width();
```

(In your example, you are just setting the string `img.width` to the w variable instead of getting the *value* itself)

Next, just add 10 to the `w` variable and write back to `img.width`. Same goes for the `h` variable.

And finally, write back the updated value:

```
image.width(w);
```

Same goes for the [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/).

Assuming you want to animate the growth (and not just make it 10px bigger once), take a look at the [jQuery animate documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more information on animating elements.

For example to animate the image to become 100px wider use something like this:

```
image.animate({"width": "+=100px"}, "slow");
```

(according to the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) documentation)

Comment: hey Veger, you are right i want to animate the image. can you have look at my code as you said i added 10 to variable w and h and called updated value but it will not zoomin the image. but zoomout works fine. can you correct if i am wrong. thanks for reply.

Comment: I updated my answer to match your example and added some correction for things you are doing wrong. Also take a look at the examples in the jQuery documentation to see how things are done using jQuery. Those examples are very helpful